# How do I install Cytoscape on Google Colab?

Tags: ubuntu, google-colaboratory, cytoscape

I'd like to use Cytoscape.js (https://js.cytoscape.org/) on Google Colab. I found here (https://py2cytoscape.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) that this can be done in Jupyter Notebooks, but the documentation isn't very thorough.

Here is the code I ran to try to set up Cytoscape and CyREST (paste each block of code here into a separate cell in Google Colab):

```
%%shell
# Install dependencies
pip install py2cytoscape
pip install dash dash-html-components
pip install dash-cytoscape
apt install g++ make libxml2-dev python-dev python3-dev zlib1g-dev

# Clone Cytoscape from Git and install
cd /usr/local/envs/cytoscape
wget https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape/releases/download/3.8.0/Cytoscape_3_8_0_unix.sh
chmod u+x  Cytoscape_3_8_0_unix.sh
sudo sh Cytoscape_3_8_0_unix.sh -q

# Run Cytoscape to check that everything was installed correctly
Cytoscape &
```

```
# Start Cytoscape
!Cytoscape &

from py2cytoscape.data.cyrest_client import CyRestClient

cy = CyRestClient()
network = cy.network.create(name='My Network', collection='My network collection')
print(network.get_id())
```

This gave me the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ConnectionRefusedError                    Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py in _new_conn(self)
    158             conn = connection.create_connection(
--> 159                 (self._dns_host, self.port), self.timeout, **extra_kw)
    160 

23 frames
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

NewConnectionError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
NewConnectionError: <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f822bd80860>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

MaxRetryError                             Traceback (most recent call last)
MaxRetryError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=1234): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/styles/visualproperties (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f822bd80860>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ConnectionError                           Traceback (most recent call last)
/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/requests/adapters.py in send(self, request, stream, timeout, verify, cert, proxies)
    514                 raise SSLError(e, request=request)
    515 
--> 516             raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
    517 
    518         except ClosedPoolError as e:

ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=1234): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1/styles/visualproperties (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7f822bd80860>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused',))
```

I found this piece of code somewhere that is supposed to help with starting CyREST, but running it gave me the exact same error as above (which I don't really understand)

```
REST_PORT = '1234' # Set to whatever rest.port is in Cytoscape preferences
REST_ENDPOINT = "http://localhost:{}/v1".format(REST_PORT)
import requests
import json
import os
from urllib.request import urlretrieve
from IPython.display import Image, display, HTML

response = requests.get(REST_ENDPOINT)
js_resp = response.json()
assert js_resp['apiVersion'] == 'v1', \
    "This notebook uses CyREST API v1, but version {} was found.".format(js_resp['apiVersion'])

print("CyREST v1 is running!")
```

My guess is that this is a problem with the ports in the Google Colab Ubuntu environment, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Comment: What did you try, and what error did you encounter?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For anyone else who runs into this issue, I learned that instead of using this approach, an easier one is to use `ipycytoscape`, which makes it much easier to get everything running.

However, the problem with both this approach and the one I described in the question is that Cytoscape relies on some ipywidgets for output, and these aren't supported in Google Colab yet.

You can follow the progress of this issue here: https://github.com/googlecolab/colabtools/issues/60